# How to deal with a MultiObjectsReturned Error

Tags: django, django-views

I have come across this error as i try to load a page. `get() returned more than one Item -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {}`

here is the view that renders the page:

```
def get_category(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all().prefetch_related('item')
    # need to evaluate the HTTP method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # add to order..create the bound form
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = forms.PartialOrderItemForm(request.POST,postdata)
        # check validation of posted data
        if form.is_valid():

            order.add_to_order(request)
            # if test cookie worked, get rid of it
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url =urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
            # redirect to order page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        # it's a GET, create the unbound from. Note request as a Kwarg
        form = forms.PartialOrderItemForm(request.GET)
    # set the test cookie on our first GET request
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    context={
        'categories':categories,
        'form':form,
#       'menu':menu,

    }
    return render_to_response('category.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This view calls the following function at some point after `is_valid`,

```
def add_to_order(request):  
    postdata = request.POST.copy()
    #get quantity added, return 0 if empty
    quantity = postdata.get('quantity',0)
    # fetch the item or return  missing page error_message
    i = get_object_or_404(Item,)
    # get items in order
    order_items = get_order_items(request)
    item_in_orders = False
    # check to see if item is already in order
    for order_item in order_items:
        if order_item.item.id == i.id:
            #update the quantity if found
            order_item.augment_quantity(quantity)
            item_in_orders = True
    if not item_in_orders:
        # creat and save a new order item
        oi = OrderItem()
        oi.order_id = _order_id(request)
        oi.quantity = quantity
        oi.item = i
        oi.save()
```

and here is the Traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/f4l/live/views.py" in get_category
  26.           order.add_to_order(request)
File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/f4l/cart/order.py" in add_to_order
  42.   i = get_object_or_404(Item,)

File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in get_object_or_404
  113.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  368.                 % (self.model._meta.object_name, num, kwargs))

Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned at /menu/
Exception Value: get() returned more than one Item -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {}
```

Thank you .

Comment: You mean other than using `filter()` instead of `get()`?

Comment: well i think the issue is being able to have a lookup for get()

Answer (score 2):

In your line `i = get_object_or_404(Item,)` tries to get the item, but you haven't specified any filter query for it, so it will try `Item.objects.get()` which will return all objects (similar to `Item.objects.all()`). [`.get()` and `get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) raises `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception when there are multiple objects for the given query.

So you need to update your line to something like:

```
i = get_object_or_404(Item, id=someid)
```

Comment: so when i do that it looks up only the item of that id, what can i do for it to look up all

Comment: i mean for it to look up all Items by id.

Comment: @Mats_invasion, Not sure what do you mean by that. There will be one item with an id, isn't it? If you really mean to get multiple items, may be you should use `get_list_or_404`.