# Django class view - MultipleObjectsReturned error

Tags: django, django-views

I'm still new at django so please bear with me. I'm trying to make a website about books. Now I'm having error like this

> MultipleObjectsReturned at /premium/1/
>   get() returned more than one Book -- it returned 2!

I don't know where to look for the error. Here is my example code.

```
class PageDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        book = get_object_or_404(Book)
        page = get_object_or_404(Page)
        user_membership = get_object_or_404(Customer, user=request.user)
        user_membership_type = user_membership.membership.membership_type
        user_allowed = book.allowedMembership.all()
        context = {'object': None}
        if user_allowed.filter(membership_type=user_membership_type).exists():
            context = {'object': page}
        return render(request, "catalog/page_detail.html", context)
```

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py"
>   in dispatch
>     52.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\admin\thesis\blackink_website\catalog\views.py" in get
>     127.         book = get_object_or_404(Book)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py"
>   in get_object_or_404
>     93.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py"
>   in get
>     403.             (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
>
> Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned at /premium/1/ Exception
>   Value: get() returned more than one Book -- it returned 2!

I will update the post if the information is not enough. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

here's my models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):


title = models.CharField(max_length=200) #i deleted some info to make it shorter

allowedMembership = models.ManyToManyField(Membership, blank=True)


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('book-detail',  args=[str(self.id)])

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

@property
def pages(self):
    return self.page_set.all()



class Page(models.Model):
book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
file = models.FileField(upload_to='book_content', validators=[pdf_file_extension], help_text="PDF File Only")
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


def __str__(self):
    return self.book.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('page-detail',   args=[str(self.id)])
```

page_detail.html

```
{% if user_membership and user_membership.user == request.user %}
        {% for content in book.pages %}
            <a href="{{ content.get_absolute_url }}" class="site-btn">Read</a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <button class="site-btn" disabled="disabled">VIP</button>
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: Is there a model relationship between your `Book` and `Page`? Please post your `models.py`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with a MultiObjectsReturned Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332792/how-to-deal-with-a-multiobjectsreturned-error)

Comment: i posted my models.py.

Comment: `get_object_or_404` expects to return a single object. `book = get_object_or_404(Book)` is failing because there are two books in the database. Which book do you want to fetch? On the next line you have `page = get_object_or_404(Page)` - which page do you want to fetch? Finally, please show your URL patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **MultipleObjectsReturned** exception is raised by a query if only one object is expected, but multiple objects are returned. A base version of this exception is provided in **django.core.exceptions**; each model class contains a subclassed version that can be used to identify the specific object type that has returned multiple objects.

> I am assuming that you are using the recent Django version. See the proper documentation based on your own version by switching from very bottom the official site.

The following would be a best links for you.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception

Just try like this, I have not tested but I am sure it will work as I had already tested before. Also check the above documentation & that is enough to get rid of this problem.

Configure your url based on [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#extending-generic-views) so that you could pass `page_id` and your url pattern should look something like `path('pages/<int:page_id>', PageDetailView.as_view())` or `re_path("^pages/(?<page_id>\d+)$", PageDetailView. as_view())`.

> Be careful while using **path()**, **re_path()**, **url()** as they have their own style + advantage.

#### Update:

After looking into the relationship between Book (parent model) and Page (child model), I changed the urlpattern from `path('pages/<int:page_id>/books/<int:book'` to `path('pages/<page_id>` and id of page is enough to fetch related book as there's a **ForeignKey** relationship between both the model.

> As your view is **PageDetailView**, it's good to pass only id of the page for better design as others suggest (you can pass several url parameters too based on requirements but here we don't need).

```
from django.http import Http404

class PageDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # page = get_object_or_404(Page)
            page_id = self.kwargs["page_id"]
            page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_id) 

            # book = get_object_or_404(Book)
            book_id = page.book.pk
            book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)

            # user_membership = get_object_or_404(Customer, user=request.user)
            user_membership = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)

            user_membership_type = user_membership.membership.membership_type
            user_allowed = book.allowedMembership.all()
            context = {'object': None}
            if user_allowed.filter(membership_type=user_membership_type).exists():
                context = {'object': page}
            return render(request, "catalog/page_detail.html", context)
        except Book.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Book with id {0} does not exist".format(book_id))
        except Page.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Page with id {0} does not exist".format(page_id))
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Cutomer does not exist")
        except Exception as e: 
            raise Exception(str(e))
```

Comment: i've tried this and i got this kind of error.. Reverse for 'page-detail' with arguments '('2',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['books/(?P<book_id>[^/]+)/page/(?P<page_id>[^/]+)$']

Comment: Can you paste the urlpattern for this and tell me the version of Django you are using?

Comment: Also check if you are using `{% url 'page-detail' book_id=1 page_id=2 %}` etc.  in template. There may be number of reasons for this. It is urlpattern related issue. Also tell me when you got this error. While clicking on any link or just after running `manage.py runserver`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336076/django-reverse-for-detail-with-arguments-and-keyword-arguments-n and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/ for your version of Django (for url template tag, if this is issue after clicking on any link of UI or because of invalid template tag syntax).

Comment: Hi~ i think its getting closer. i Updated my post again.

Comment: I have updated my answer and also changed the urlpattern. Please try and let me know if you are still stuck. As **Book** is the parent model of **Page** model, you don't need to pass 2 parameters on urlpattern now. You can get a book's  **pk** using `page.book.pk`. Number of pages can belong to a single **Book** instance.

Comment: And here we are seeing Exception while fetching Book instance, this time you won't get it as **page.book.pk** will give you the related unique instance of **Book** for any **Page**.

Comment: It's now working. I will be testing it to check if there will be any other issues. So, thank you for getting me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are using `get_object_or_404` to get a *single* book, but the issue is your query is returning *multiple* books. This usually happens when there is no unique constraint on the field you use to lookup the book with (i.e. getting object by the **title** "Jungle Book" returns two books with the same title).

To fix this, get the object using a field that is guaranteed to be unique, such as an *id*. For example:

**urls.py**

```
path('page-details/<str:book_id>/<str:page_id>/', PageDetailView.as_view(), name='page_details'),
```

**views.py**

```
class PageDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        book = get_object_or_404(id=kwargs['book_id'])
        page = get_object_or_404(id=kwargs['page_id'])
        [...]
```

Comment: i've tried this but i got Reverse for 'page-detail' not found. 'page-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name. error.

Comment: @GiranyxPornasdoro anywhere you have “page-detail” in `reverse`, change it to “page_details” to match the URL name I used

Comment: uhm its still the same i think.. it says NoReverseMatch at /book-detail/1/
Reverse for 'page_details' with arguments '('1',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['page\\-details/(?P<book_id>[^/]+)/(?P<page_id>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: @GiranyxPornasdoro add your `urls.py` in your post so I can see whats going on